# Passing NSIndexPath to New View

Tags: objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I am having real troubles passing an NSIndexPath to my new view. This is how the app works:

I have a UIBarButtonItem in my nab br, tap that and you get a popover view, this shows a bunch of stuff. I need to get an NSIndexPath from my main view, to this popover view.

I have a property for the NSIndexPath in my popover view class and the popover transition is connected up in my storyboard.

Then I have this code to pass the index path across views:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"statsPopover"])
    {
        StatsViewController *statsVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        statsVC.selectedIndex = stageSelectionTable.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    }
}
```

However, while this gets called, the index path isn't actually sent between views. My index path on the popover is always the default, 0,0 row and section.

Comment: how do you "fill" `stageSelectionTable.indexPathForSelectedRow`?

Comment: 'while this gets called' - how do you know? If you set a breakpoint on the line starting `statsVC.selectedIndex...` what happens?

Comment: I know that `stageSelectionTable.indexPathForSelectedRow` has the values I want in it as I have logged it directly before sending it to its new view. I also know that it gets called, because I have set breakpoint and it runs that line. What I don't understand is why the value is being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you know from debugging/logging that the method is running, your `if` statement is triggered, and `stageSelectionTable.indexPathForSelectedRow` has the value you expect.

Doing that kind of diagnosis puts you on the right path to solving your issue. Keep at it -- if you test some other things with `NSLog` or the debugger you should be able to find the problem.

- Do you know that `statsVC` is non-`nil`? If it's `nil`, your message to set `selectedIndex` does nothing.
- Is `statsVC` the class you expect? If, say, the (table?) view in your popover is embedded in a navigation controller, `segue.destinationViewController` will point to the nav controller, and you'll need to look into its child view controllers array to find the one you're looking for.
- Is whatever accessor method your `StatsViewController` class is using for its `selectedIndex` property working right? (This shouldn't be a problem if it's a synthesized accessor for a strong/retain property.)
- In your `StatsViewController` class, are you trying to work with `selectedIndex` before it actually gets set? Setting a property in `prepareForSegue:sender:` and then using it in `viewDidLoad` should work fine, but using it in `awakeFromNib` might not, and using it in an `init...` method definitely won't.